# Is it possible to print PDF slides off-centre?

Tags: pdf, printing, adobe-acrobat

not sure sure where to ask this: I have a slideshow in PDF format from class (it is only available as PDF, no other formats).

I wanted to print the slides off-centre on the paper. For example, have two slides side-by-side at the top of the page and then empty space all below. I've searched around settings in Acrobat Reader and in my printer settings and cannot find a way to print the slides off-centre. By default everything prints right in the middle of the paper.

Is it possible to print off-centre with a PDF (either with Adobe Acrobat Reader or some other program)? Or is there a free way I can modify the PDF to add blank slides to it?

Comment: Try an alternative such as PDF-XChange Viewer and adjust the size to custom scale, and don't select auto-center on page. https://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-viewer

Comment: the open-source tools for *nix described there might be interesting (should be available for cygwin too, or maybe wsl?) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16158435/add-margin-to-pdf-file-when-merging-using-pdftk-or-similar